# memento objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу реализировать паттерн memento .Моя проблема заключается в тому ,что я хочу сохранить состояние игры даже когда юзер закрыл игру . По-сути мне нужно как-то сохранить Объект _deck Немного погуглив я сделал так

```
- (void)saveCurrentState
{    
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_deck forKey:@"currentDeck"];
    NSLog(@"save");
}

- (void)loadPreviousState
{
    _deck = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentDeck"];
    [self updateCardWrapForAllCards];
    NSLog(@"load");
}
```

создал notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(saveCurrentState) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

ну вот а теперь когда ухожу в бэк граунд то програма падает.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: падает после NSLog или до?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko до)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе deck вам надо написать два метода приведенные ниже (заменить все объекты на реальные объекты из вашего класса)

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.question forKey:@"question"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.categoryName forKey:@"category"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.subCategoryName forKey:@"subcategory"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.question = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"question"];
        self.categoryName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"category"];
        self.subCategoryName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"subcategory"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Прочитать и записать в user defaults:

```
- (void)saveCustomObject:(MyObject *)object key:(NSString *)key {
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:key];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

- (MyObject *)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:key];
    MyObject *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    return object;
}
```

Код нагло взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: спасибо.Буду пробовать.